# Class within a class generating 'name 'self' is not defined' error

Tags: python, oop

I have the following code

```
class Classifiers(object):
    """Multiple classifiers"""

    class RandomForest(self): # this line generate error 
        """
        Random Forest Classifier Object.
        """
        @staticmethod
        def classifier(X, y):
            from sklearn import ensemble as ens
            classifier = ens.RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=15)
            return(X,y,classifier)
```

But why it generate this error:

```
----> 5     class RandomForest(self):
      6         """
      7         Random Forest Classifier Object.

NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

At the end of the day, I'd call it this way:

```
rf = Classifiers.RandomForest()
X, y, rf_clsf   = rf.classifier(some_X_, some_y_)
```

All in all what's the elegant and correct way to implement the above OO code?
Given this kind of problem how would you do it?

Comment: What do you expect `class RandomForest(self)` to mean?

Comment: while inheriting you should give the class name, not object name. self is the object. and you haven't defined self yet

Comment: Why do you feel you need `RandomForest` to be inside `Classifier` instead of just a separate class outside it?

Comment: @BrenBarn: For the sake of clarity. Because there are other classes.

Comment: @neversaint: That's not really how classes work.  If you want to group multiple classes together, put them into a module, not inside another class.

Comment: @BrenBarn: Module as in an independent `*.py` file?

Answer (score 1):

this record

```
class Classifiers(object)
```

means what class `Classifiers` [is child of `object`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html). Because `RandomForest` is part of `Classifiers` it can't be child of `Classifiers`. So class `RandomForest(self)` construction is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

You must declare not `self` in signature of `RandomForest`. `self` is a `Classifiers` and `self` used for access to `Classifiers` atributes. You must use class `__init__` of `RandomForest`

```
class Classifiers(object):
    class RandomForest():
        def __init__(otherself, Classifiers): #RandomForest's constructor. otherself here is analog self of Classifiers
            otherself.a = 1
        pass
    def __init__(self): #Classifiers's constructor
        self.b = 2
c = Classifiers()
print c.RandomForest(c).a
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason you generally define class methods with `self` as the first argument is that (unless you've turned it into a static method) the method automatically gets passed the current instance as the first argument.

`self` is just the conventional name to give to that instance, `self` doesn't actually have any special meaning within a class definition.

If you want your `RandomForest` class to inherit from `Classifiers`, you should just do:

```
class Classifiers(object):
    """Multiple classifiers"""
    # Rest of the Classifiers definition

class RandomForest(Classifiers):
```

I'm not sure what benefit you were hoping to get from having the nested class definiton, if you can explain that there might be a different way to achieve it.